# Element with margin auto does not center inside of parent with display flex in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

An image with the property margin-auto does not vertically and horizontally center within its parent which has the property display flex. This issue is **only** prevalent on chrome. I've tested this on Brave (my main browser), Firefox and Microsoft Edge.

Took screenshots of Brave and Chrome to show you what the issue is and what it should look like
Brave (how it should look like): http://prntscr.com/nn8zeu
Chrome: http://prntscr.com/nn8zp3

I'm using bootstrap, so for those of you who are unfamiliar with the class names.

m-auto = margin: auto

d-flex = display: flex

**Code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container mt-4">
    <h1 class="mb-1">Hi Stackoverflow</h1>
    <p>The item below is div with display flex and some styles to make it round and look pretty. <br> The image inside has margin-auto. Why does image <b>Not</b> center on chrome?. pls help</p>
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
      <div class="icon mr-2 d-flex">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/420/discord-logo.png" alt="" class="img m-auto">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>

<style>
  .icon {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: lightseagreen;
  }
  
  .img {
    width: 25px;
    height: auto;
    filter: invert(100%);
  }
</style>
```

Comment: images are **inline** elements and aren't affected by margin. Just use flex properties to center it.

Comment: Could you give me an example of code. Not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: I made a [runnable code snippet](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MdeBzx) of your code, and I can't reproduce your issue on chrome. Maybe there are some other rules at play that interfere with your centering?

Comment: @PiotrWicijowski, I managed to solve the issue using flex-direction: column, on the parent div. Thank you none the less for taking the time to create the snippet. appreciate your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example to center the image in the `.icon` class div, by setting display to flex, and aligning and justifying everything to center. I added 4 lines of code to the top of the `.icon` selector in the css.

```css
.icon {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
}

.img {
  width: 25px;
  height: auto;
  filter: invert(100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container mt-4">
    <h1 class="mb-1">Hi Stackoverflow</h1>
    <p>The item below is div with display flex and some styles to make it round and look pretty. <br> The image inside has margin-auto. Why does image <b>Not</b> center on chrome?. pls help</p>
    <div class="d-flex">
      <div class="icon mr-2 d-flex">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/420/discord-logo.png" alt="" class="img m-auto">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps! Have a nice day :)

Comment: Thank you very much. The flex-direction: column solved my issue beautifully. Appreciate it immensely